# Better way to repeatedly get the position of elements in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of integers (from 0 to N) and I need to create a new list which contains the indexes of each integer in the first list.

That is, given

```
s = [4, 2, 6, 3, 0, 5, 1]
```

determine `r` such that `s[r[i]] = i`

```
r = [4, 6, 1, 3, 0, 5, 2]
```

My current solution is

```
r = [s.index(i) for i in xrange(len(s))]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Seems like a pretty good approach to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that each integer in `S` appears exactly once. Your current solution will work, the problem is that `s.index` performs an `O(N)` search, making this an `O(N**2)` operation.

For a large list, I would expect the following code to be faster since it is `O(N)`

```
# initialise the whole list with some value
r = [-1]*N

for j, s_j in enumerate(s):
    r[s_j] = j

# if any element of r is still -1 then you know it did not appear in s
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a dictionary would be better for this:

```
s = [4, 2, 6, 3, 0, 5, 1]
r = dict((v,i) for i,v in enumerate(s))
```

testing:

```
>>> for i,_ in enumerate(s):
...     print i, s[r[i]]
... 
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally the approach you showed is great.

Either a dictionary would work - that would be my first try:

```
r = {v:i for i, v in enumerate(s)}
```

Or if you have to use a list another approach is:

```
r = [x[0] for x in sorted(enumerate(s), key=lambda v:v[1])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you allowed to use `numpy` ?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = np.array([4, 2, 6, 3, 0, 5, 1])
>>> s.argsort()
array([4, 6, 1, 3, 0, 5, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 2):

i did a simple benchmark with the timit module @10^6 iterations - 5 repetitions.

```
DaveP :       1.16 +/- 0.04s

koblas:       7.02s +/- 0.04s

Jon Clements: 1.82 +/- 0.02s

Zero Piraeus: 6.04 +/- 0.4s
```

and last but not least:

```
r=s[:]
[r[s[i]] for i in s]
```

my suggestion: 1.11 +/- 0.03s